# How do I serialize a JavaScript object and then write it to a JSON file wihout node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, state

How do I write a JSON Serialized JavaScript object to a text file to read later on in JavaScript without using Node.js?

I am trying to maintain state in my objects and my work does not allow node.js.

Thanks!

Comment: What JavaScript environment are you using if it's not node.js? A browser? If so, what kinds of browsers are you targeting?

Comment: Well where does this object exist? In client (browser) code? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You will need a server side language. JS can not write files directly to your desktop from a browser environment.

Comment: Also, why tag node.js if you can't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write to a local computer file system using JS (i.e. to a text file as you say in your original question.)

However, you can write to a persistent object, `localStorage`, which will allow you to store information between sessions. Like so:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
```

This information persists betweens sessions, so you can later call `getItem` to retrieve information:

```
localStorage.getItem('key') // === 'value'
```

This way, you could store information in the local browser. Not all browsers support this - for more information, check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

In frontend, you can use sessionStorage, localStorage or, if the browser implement the technology, webSQL

SessionStorage will keep the data till the user change the tab. LocalStorage will store the data even if the user close the browser and open it again. Finally, webSQL is not implement by many browser, so, try to avoid it.